# Not found : /lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/tensorboard/lib/svg/summary-icon.sv

Tags: python, firefox, tensorflow, tensorboard

I am using tensorboard to visualize the graphs and minimization of objective function. I can visualize the the loss function but can not visualize the graph. I get a not found error

```
WARNING:tensorflow:IOError [Errno 2] No such file or directory:  /lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/tensorboard/lib/svg/summary-icon.sv
```

[image: When clicked on GRAPH]
[image: loss minimization curve]

[EDIT]

```
  pip show tensorflow
  ---
  Name: tensorflow 
  Version: 0.6.0
```

[EDIT2]
When I switched to another browser, (chromium), it works. But does not work with Firefox.
[image: Graph with Chromium]

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR:** This issue was fixed in version 0.6.0 of TensorFlow, so upgrading to that version should fix it.

The file `summary-icon.svg` was [removed from TensorFlow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/f7918e1dcd5b0c1f8114f488fc35a63a81e94535) in version 0.6.0, and replaced with an embedded image. Is it possible that you have an installation that mixes versions 0.5.0 and 0.6.0 of TensorFlow (or some intermediate version that is built from source)?

Comment: I upgraded tensorflow into 0.6 but facing the same problem:

Comment: Can you try [installing TensorFlow into a virtualenv](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup.html#virtualenv_install) and running TensorBoard from there? It's possible that there are some left-over files from the previous version that are causing this problem.